# Bibliography processing issue with TeXstudio: "I couldn't open file name `build/bibliographyCitation.aux'"

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texstudio

I'm new using TeXstudio and I'm trying to cite the references in my work. But unfortunately I had an error says:

```
Process started: bibtex build/"bibliographyCitation"

I couldn't open file name `build/bibliographyCitation.aux'

Process exited normally
```

I searched about solutions for this problem but no one specify how can I know the default folder that has the .aux file? and how can I change it step by step?!

This is the current settings I have:
[image: TeXstudio Settings]

Thank you

Comment: At the line *BibTeX*, write: `bibtex %` instead of `bibtex build/%`.

Comment: @ebo I did and still have [?] instead of the citation :(

Comment: Your problem is then solved `(-;` ! Have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/64454). I suggest you to take some time to browse some introduction to LaTeX (e.g. the [(not) so short one](http://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)): it's worth the time/effort invested in it!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336802/bibliography-error-couldnt-open-file-aux

Answer (score 4):

### The theory

In your settings, the bash command associated with *BibTeX* is: `bibtex build/%`. It means: "*look for the (implicitely said `.aux`) file in following folder: `<location of the .tex file you're compiling>/build`*".
This is handy when you tell (pdf)LaTeX to put every temporary/auxiliary files in a subfolder (here name `build`) in order to keep the original folder "clean". You activate this behavior using the `-output-directory` option while running (pdf)LaTeX (e.g., `pdflatex -output-directory=build/ %.tex`).

### Your case

However, since you did not enabled this feature (i.e., the bash command used for (pdf)LaTeX compiling does not call the `-output-directory` option), all temp files are created in the same folder than the `.tex` file you are compiling.
But in your case, `bibtex` is still looking for the `.aux`-file in a non-existing subfolder named `build`: `bibtex build/%`.

### The solution

Thus, you should tell `bibtex` to look for the `.aux` file in the same folder than your `.tex` file, i.e. **write `bibtex %` instead of `bibtex build/%` at the *BibTeX* line**.

(Or you could also create a subfolder named `build`, and use following commands: *pdfLaTeX*: `pdflatex -output-directory=build/ %.tex`; *bibTeX*: `bibtex build/%`. But you would also need to update paths for other commands (e.g. pdf-viewer).)

Comment: I tried the two options and the last option I tried is : http://www.4shared.com/photo/u2IPH1cNba/18-01-38_11-20-39_AM.html

Comment: And here is what I got : http://www.4shared.com/photo/UxwVet0_ba/18-01-38_11-20-18_AM.html

Comment: As detailed in the *"What to do"* section of the [selected answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/64454) of the linked question (see comment above), you need to compile your document as following: `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` (some explanations [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334456/64454)). Your issue is thus now likely due to insufficient number of compilation of your document. In other word, try running `pdflatex` twice.

Comment: sadly no :( I decided to leave the whole application and use MS with endnote to do the bibliography:( It's not what I want but I did that just to gain time because it's easy to use but not efficient output as TeXstudio. Definitely I will try later to solve it:(

Comment: sadly no :( I decided to leave the whole application and use MS with endnote to do the bibliography:( It's not what I want but I did that just to gain time because it's easy to use but not efficient output as TeXstudio. Definitely I will try later to solve it:(

Comment: @F505 Yup, I understand... I can only say it's worth trying again! Have a look on [minimal working examples with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407), and try to create one. If it's not working, post your issue (and what you've tried to solve it) in a new question!