# bibliography error: couldn't open file .aux

Tags: bibliographies, errors

I am having issues with my bibliography.

I've created a file called '`MyLibrary.bib`', which has all of the data for my references. I created this by exporting from Zotero. It seems to have exported without issues.

I have cited in my main document, called 'Lit Review.tex' and it gave me an error saying that there were undefined references. At the end of my Lit Review.tex, I have put the commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{MyLibrary}
```

I ran BibTex (F11), and it said that it couldn't open file name '`MyLibrary.aux`'. and exited the process with error(s).

Any suggestions about what to do next? Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: Did you compile `tex` file first?

Comment: yes I did ~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: if your main file is called `Lit Review` (side remark: better remove the space from the file name)  then bibtex should run `Lit Review.aux` and not `MyLibrary.aux`. Did you change the configuration of your editor?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: yes my main file is called Lit Review. No, I don't think I've changed the configuration.

Comment: I've tried rerunning it all and have changed Lit Review -> LitReview

Comment: However, it still says 'I couldnt' open file name 'MyLibrary.aux' when I try to BibTex MyLibrary.bib

Comment: Don't bibtex `MyLibrary.bib`, but `LitReview`. bibtex will look into `LitReview.aux` and there will find the information to use `MyLibrary.bib` (as well as which references are needed).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to add an answer or do we have a suitable duplicate around? Maybe even question marks intead of citation number?

Comment: @Johannes_B There is probably a duplicate as the problem is quite standard but I don't have the time to search so I added an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334743/bibliography-processing-issue-with-texstudio-i-couldnt-open-file-name-build

Answer (score 3):

### bibtex compiles `aux`-files and **not** `bib`-files!

This means: If your main file is called `LitReview.tex` and your bib-file is called `MyLibrary.bib`)  then the call to bibtex should do

```
 bibtex LitReview.aux
```

or

```
 bibtex LitReview
```

**It should not (!) be**

```
 bibtex MyLibrary.bib
```

or

```
 bibtex MyLibrary
```

Side remark: I removed the space from the name of your main file to avoid to have to quote it.

Comment: Another question off the list, thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, this is so counter-intuitive, very poor UX in my opinion. Everything is so all over the place with LaTeX...